# Saving Images from Image Control isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, save

I have a Image (Frameworkelement) on my GUI.
There is a image in there. Now I'm performing a doubleclick at this image and I want, that
the Image saves itself and is going to be opened, with the default imageviewer.

My Code:

```
void image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Wayaround, cause there is no DoubleClick Event on Image 
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left && e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        SaveToPng(((Image)sender), "SavedPicture.png");
        Process.Start("SavedPicture.png");
    }
}

void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
}

void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)visual.ActualWidth,
        (int)visual.ActualHeight,
        96,
        96,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

    using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Opening the picture works fine with `Process.Start`. The problem is the saving, well it saves the picture: `SavedPicture.png` but, Its just black, so theres no graphic.. Maybe someone could tell me, whats wrong in my code or knows a better way of saving a image in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used this: `File.WriteAllBytes()` 
to save the image from binaryformat

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary that the image is displayed before it is saved. So, if you want to use `RenderTargetBitmap` just set the `Image.Source` and load the `Image` before saving with `SaveToPng` (`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` must not be null).

***Example***:

If you have the `Image` inside a `Panel`:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Image x:Name="MyImage"/>
</Grid>
```

I set `Image.Source` in my test class constructor, and only after the image was loaded i save it:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.BeginInit();
    bmp.UriSource = new Uri("image.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bmp.EndInit();
    MyImage.Source = bmp;

}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)MyGrid.ActualWidth,
            (int)MyGrid.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

    bmp.Render(MyImage);
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create("newimage.png"))
    { encoder.Save(stream); }
}
```

If you don't want to use `Grid` `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` just pass your with and height as arguments.

Comment: the Image is displayed. I don't need to use RenderTargetBitmap, I asked if there are easier and better ways. Could u provide some example code, of what u actually mean with setting Image.Source to RenderTargetBitmap? Thank you

Comment: well the result is the same.. It saves a "newimage.png", but when I open it with any Imageviewer its plain or just black - no content.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of the Image.Source, assuming that you have a BitmapSource as in the article it should be along those lines:

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)image.Source));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    encoder.Save(stream);
```

by the way RenderTargetBitmap  class is to Converts a Visual object into a bitmap. its recommended by the team

sample 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969819.aspx

Comment: just out of curiosity, what's team?